# GNU MCU Eclipse compiles files but no object (.o) files

Tags: microcontroller, eclipse

I'm trying to make GNU MCU Eclipse work with my XMC4800 Relax kit and a existing project. Which is taking me more time than it should. Right now the files compile fine, that means, without errors, but when Linking starts the compiler says that it can't find any *.o files:

```
make all 
make: Warning: File 'objects.mk' has modification time 5026 s in the future
Building file: ../src/main.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o" -c -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.c"
Finished building: ../src/main.c

Building file: ../src/objectlist.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"src/objectlist.d" -MT"src/objectlist.o" -c -o "src/objectlist.o" "../src/objectlist.c"
Finished building: ../src/objectlist.c

Building file: ../src/soes.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"src/soes.d" -MT"src/soes.o" -c -o "src/soes.o" "../src/soes.c"
Finished building: ../src/soes.c

Building file: ../include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw.d" -MT"include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw.o" -c -o "include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw.o" "../include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw.c"
Finished building: ../include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw.c

Building file: ../include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw_eep.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw_eep.d" -MT"include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw_eep.o" -c -o "include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw_eep.o" "../include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw_eep.c"
Finished building: ../include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw_eep.c

Building file: ../include/soes/esc.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/soes/esc.d" -MT"include/soes/esc.o" -c -o "include/soes/esc.o" "../include/soes/esc.c"
Finished building: ../include/soes/esc.c

Building file: ../include/soes/esc_coe.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/soes/esc_coe.d" -MT"include/soes/esc_coe.o" -c -o "include/soes/esc_coe.o" "../include/soes/esc_coe.c"
Finished building: ../include/soes/esc_coe.c

Building file: ../include/soes/esc_eep.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/soes/esc_eep.d" -MT"include/soes/esc_eep.o" -c -o "include/soes/esc_eep.o" "../include/soes/esc_eep.c"
Finished building: ../include/soes/esc_eep.c

Building file: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_flash.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_flash.d" -MT"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_flash.o" -c -o "include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_flash.o" "../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_flash.c"
Finished building: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_flash.c

Building file: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_gpio.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_gpio.d" -MT"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_gpio.o" -c -o "include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_gpio.o" "../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_gpio.c"
Finished building: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_gpio.c

Building file: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_scu.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_scu.d" -MT"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_scu.o" -c -o "include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_scu.o" "../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_scu.c"
Finished building: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_scu.c

Building file: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_ecat.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_ecat.d" -MT"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_ecat.o" -c -o "include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_ecat.o" "../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_ecat.c"
Finished building: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_ecat.c

Building file: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_fce.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_fce.d" -MT"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_fce.o" -c -o "include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_fce.o" "../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_fce.c"
Finished building: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_fce.c

Building file: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_gpio.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_gpio.d" -MT"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_gpio.o" -c -o "include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_gpio.o" "../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_gpio.c"
Finished building: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_gpio.c

Building file: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/Newlib/syscalls.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/Newlib/syscalls.d" -MT"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/Newlib/syscalls.o" -c -o "include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/Newlib/syscalls.o" "../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/Newlib/syscalls.c"
Finished building: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/Newlib/syscalls.c

Building file: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/system_XMC4800.c
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -DDEBUG -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -DTRACE -DOS_USE_TRACE_SEMIHOSTING_DEBUG -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I../include/soes -I../include/soes/hal/xmc4 -I../include/soes/include/sys/gcc -I../src -std=gnu11 -Wmissing-prototypes -Wbad-function-cast -MMD -MP -MF"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/system_XMC4800.d" -MT"include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/system_XMC4800.o" -c -o "include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/system_XMC4800.o" "../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/system_XMC4800.c"
Finished building: ../include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/system_XMC4800.c

Building target: test1543.elf
Invoking: GNU ARM Cross C++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -Og -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-move-loop-invariants -fsyntax-only -pedantic -pedantic-errors -w -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wpadded -Wshadow -Wlogical-op -Waggregate-return -Wfloat-equal  -g3 -T ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/GCC/XMC4800x2048 -nostartfiles -L"../ldscripts" -Wl,-Map,"test1543.map" --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -o "test1543.elf"  ./src/main.o ./src/objectlist.o ./src/soes.o  ./include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw.o ./include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw_eep.o  ./include/soes/esc.o ./include/soes/esc_coe.o ./include/soes/esc_eep.o  ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_flash.o ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_gpio.o ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_scu.o ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_ecat.o ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_fce.o ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_gpio.o  ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/Newlib/syscalls.o  ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/system_XMC4800.o   
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./src/main.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./src/objectlist.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./src/soes.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/soes/hal/xmc4/esc_hw_eep.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/soes/esc.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/soes/esc_coe.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/soes/esc_eep.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_flash.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_gpio.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc4_scu.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_ecat.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_fce.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/src/xmc_gpio.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/Newlib/syscalls.o: No such file or directory
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: ./include/XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/system_XMC4800.o: No such file or directory
makefile:62: recipe for target 'test1543.elf' failed
make: *** [test1543.elf] Error 1
```

I don't see any *.o files appearing in the folders. So I think the compiler is not creating any object files, how do it get it to work?
The relevant setting (i hope) are in this album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAWoL.jpg

Some extra information:
The original project uses an assembler before linking files (and after compiling) and does `objcopy`:

```
Assembling: XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/GCC/startup_XMC4800.S
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -x assembler-with-cpp -DXMC4800_F144x2048 -MMD -MP -MF XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/GCC/startup_XMC4800.d -MT XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/GCC/startup_XMC4800.o -I././XMC_Peripheral_Library/XMCLib/inc -I././XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Include -I././XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Include -I. -I../soes -I../soes/hal/xmc4 -I../soes/include/sys/gcc -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -Wa,-adhlns=XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/GCC/startup_XMC4800.lst -mfloat-abi=softfp -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mthumb -o XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/GCC/startup_XMC4800.o XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/GCC/startup_XMC4800.S

ObjCopy: sii_eeprom.bin
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -I binary -O elf32-littlearm -B arm sii_eeprom.bin sii_eeprom.o
```

Also, the original make files doesn't use the `g++` linker but the `gcc` linker:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -T./XMC_Peripheral_Library/CMSIS/Infineon/XMC4800_series/Source/GCC/XMC4800x2048.ld -nostartfiles -Xlinker --gc-sections -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map,xmc4800-ecat-slave.map -mfloat-abi=softfp -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mthumb -o xmc4800-ecat-slave.elf main.o etc etc etc
```

Unfortunately I can't share the project...

Edit: I added the objcopy command to the post-build steps (according to: http://rdu.im/embedded_development/2015/02/01/setting-up-development-environment-for-mcu-using-opensource-tools-2.html), but doesn't seem to change anything.

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -I binary -O elf32-littlearm -B arm sii_eeprom.bin sii_eeprom.o
```

Edit 2: Both makefiles are here: https://gist.github.com/kwint/8969112d75807f5aff320ee03ec239b3

Comment: Share the Makefile.

Comment: Here are both: https://gist.github.com/kwint/8969112d75807f5aff320ee03ec239b3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone else struggles with this, disable `-Wpedantic` or `-pedantic`. You only need these options if your code has to meet strict ISO standards. 
Read more about this here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

See the `-MMD` `-MP`, `-MF`, `-MT` options in the gcc command line?

Have a look at the [gcc specs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/cpp/Invocation.html). This will simply produce a makefile-formatted output of the dependencies of the c source. It does not produce an object file output.

You simply did the step of dependencies analysis of the sources, not the actual compilation.

Comment: The makefile that does work also has these options, and that works. Also, I can't find how to disable these options in eclipse